# How to use the data-filter-control-container option on Bootstrap-table?

Tags: filter, bootstrap-4, custom-controls, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to set-up the new feature from filterControl but maybe I didn't understand how it works. Documentation is telling:

> Set to e.g. #filter to allow custom input filter in an element with the id filter. Each filter element (input or select) must have the following id bootstrap-table-filter-control- ( must be replaced with the defined [Field](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/column-options/#field) name).

My code example is on https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/joicy/3593

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the great demo from Saeed, I created this follow-up fiddle that showcases how to filter by more than one column. In this example, there will be two selects, one for `Name` and one for `City`. They will filter as an AND essentially, meaning if City is set to Melbourne there will be three results: Jen, Roger, and Kelly. If Name is then set to Jen, there will be one remaining result.

One nice feature that I wasn't expecting is that multiple selects can go in the same `#filter` `div`, where filter is the element specified at the end of `data-filter-control-container="#filter"`, and they will be populated correctly according to the field at the end of `bootstrap-table-filter-control-field`
https://jsfiddle.net/u6dm9eLr/2/

```html
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Bootstrap-table with multiple filter containers</h3>
      <div id="filter">
        Name
        <select class="form-control bootstrap-table-filter-control-name">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        City
        <select class="form-control bootstrap-table-filter-control-city">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-filter-control="true" data-filter-control-container="#filter">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-filter-control="select">Id</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-filter-control="select">Name</th>
            <th data-field="city" data-filter-control="select">City</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a selector for the value of data-filter-control-container property.
In your code example, you should try with '#filter' instead of 'true'.
Like that :
data-filter-control-container="#filter">

Answer (score 0):

I've created https://jsfiddle.net/SaeedYasin/k8vqcs9m/41/ to showcase how to use data-filter-control-container property. Here is the HTML,

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Bootstrap-table</h3>
  <div id="filter">
    <select class="form-control bootstrap-table-filter-control-name">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <table 
    id="table" 
    data-toggle="table" 
    data-toolbar="#toolbar" 
    data-filter-control="true" 
    data-filter-control-container="#filter"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="id" data-filter-control="select">Id</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-filter-control="select">Name</th>
        <th data-field="city" data-filter-control="select">City</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

In this example, `name` column gets the filter control container, but you can change it to any other column as well. So, instead of `bootstrap-table-filter-control-name` you can for example, change it to `bootstrap-table-filter-control-city` to make it work for column "City" instead. Also, you can add an initial value for the option as well, instead of the current empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Would this also work with three filter-controls with filterAlgorithm: 'or'?

What I am interested in creating:
https://jsfiddle.net/p8be45cr/

```
  <div id="filter_type">
    <select class="form-control bootstrap-table-filter-control-type">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="filter_owner">
    <select class="form-control bootstrap-table-filter-control-owner">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="filter_status">
    <select class="form-control bootstrap-table-filter-control-status">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <table 
    id="table" 
    data-toggle="table" 
    data-toolbar="#toolbar" 
    data-filter-control="true" 
    data-filter-control-container="#filter_type"
  >
    
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">ID</th>
      <th data-field="type">Item type</th>
      <th data-field="owner">Owner</th>
      <th data-field="value">Item value</th>
      <th data-field="status">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Boat</td>
      <td>Kim</td>
      <td>1200</td>
      <td>Docked</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Airplane</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>1400</td>
      <td>Flying</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Boat</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>Sailing</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```